# How to use my WiFi to inspect its user traffic and to run MiTM attacks?

Tags: web-application, wifi, man-in-the-middle, sniffer

As part of a security research, I need to make my WiFi open, and to inspect the traffic of the ones who connect to it.
Additionally, I need to be able to change the content of the webpages they see, and generally to act as a man in the middle.

1. Do you know relevant tools or tools that already do this?
2. Can someone give me some guidelines and relevant references?
3. Which technical problems I might face during the development process?
4. Which platforms/languages are recommended for such a project?

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to suggest [Ettercap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ettercap_%28computing%29), a free and open-source network security tool for man-in-the-middle attacks.

I recently used its [ARP spoofing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARP_spoofing) functionality in an Ethical Hacking / Penetration Testing training, and was amazed how easy it is to set up.

It's included in the [Kali Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kali_Linux) distribution.

Comment: Ettercap is a tool for ARP Spoofing. In my case, I don't need any attack to gain MITM capabilities: I control the router.

Comment: Ettercap offers other modes of operation. See the [feature list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ettercap_%28software%29#Features).

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to just set up a proxy that do whatever is needed. This article is a classic and good starting point: http://www.ex-parrot.com/pete/upside-down-ternet.html

Comment: How can I redirect all the traffic to/from my router to a proxy? Is there any generic way?

Comment: You are up to no good, are you..?

Comment: For research. It is my idea for a project in advanced cyber security course.

Comment: Are you looking for real world exploitation, or simply controlled experiment? Real world would be ARP poisoning or DNS hijacking to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

Look into [Karma](http://www.theta44.org/karma/)/[Karmetasploit](http://dev.metasploit.com/redmine/projects/framework/wiki/Karmetasploit) and the [Dsniff](http://www.monkey.org/~dugsong/dsniff/) suite of tools... Also something like Firesheep might me useful too in some cases.

At a basic level Karma/Karmetasploit is really all you need. Based on what you're asking, go look into what Karma and/or Karmetasploit (which is just Karma merged into/with Metasploit) can do.. Everything you're asking for and more. It's a brilliant tool.

Dsniff is a suite of sniffers and sniffer helpers: "Dsniff is a collection of tools for network auditing and penetration testing. dsniff, filesnarf, mailsnarf, msgsnarf, urlsnarf, and webspy passively monitor a network for interesting data (passwords, e-mail, files, etc.). arpspoof, dnsspoof, and macof facilitate the interception of network traffic normally unavailable to an attacker (e.g, due to layer-2 switching). sshmitm and webmitm implement active monkey-in-the-middle attacks against redirected SSH and HTTPS sessions by exploiting weak bindings in ad-hoc PKI."